# How can I redirect /article.html to /article.pwa.html with akamai if cookie is set?

Tags: aem, amp-html, progressive-web-apps, akamai

I'm currently working on an page that heavily relies on [Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP)](https://www.ampproject.org/) as base and also provides an extended [Progressive Web Apps (PWA)](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) version to all returning users with support for ServiceWorker. Chrome, FF and Opera users will get receive the PWA page as returning visitors, even if they use an URL for a AMP page. Safari and Internet Explorer users will see the AMP page if returning to a AMP URL. AMP pages are found on the default URL and the extended PWA version uses a HTL selector to render a page with additional functionality, e.g.:
AMP: /category/article-name.html
PWA: /category/article-name.pwa.html

I would like to redirect Safari Users from /category/article.html to /category/article.pwa.html if they are returning visitors and a cookie has been set. I couldn't find a matching example including a wildcard for article slugs (e.g. /design/got-to-know.html and /innovation/best-innovators.html) and selectors like ".pwa.html" on the akamai documentation.

Comment: Is there any strong reason to do it on Akamai only? I have normally implemented cookie rules on Apache (Dispatcher) level.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to easily configure this in the Luna Property Manager under the Redirect Rules Section. Have a look at [this](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/solutions/intelligent-platform/control-center/property-manager.jsp).